# How to change selenium-standalone port number via webdriverio wdio file?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I need to change the port number of which selenium standalone server is using by default (4444). Port 4444 is currently in use, is there a way to alter the port number via the wdio file?

```
// Test runner services
// Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
// your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
// commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
services: ['selenium-standalone'],
```

Currently I'm starting selenium server via the following command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start
```

I have also attempting to use the following with no luck:

```
./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start -port 7777
```

Running the above command still attempt to run selenium sever on port 4444.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the `selenium-standalone` on the specific port you should use the following syntax:

```
./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start -- -port 7777
```

Change the port in the `wdi.conf.js`:

```
seleniumArgs: {
  seleniumArgs: ["-port", "7777"],
},
```

Also, read more about the wdio configuration file [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile.html) and about wdio-cli [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/clioptions.html)

So, your final `wdio.conf.js` should look like:

```
exports.config = {
  /**
  * server configurations
  */
  services: ['selenium-standalone'],
  port: 7777,
  seleniumArgs: {
    seleniumArgs: ["-port", "7777"],
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Yevhen appreciate it!

Comment: hey @Yevhen, sorry to bother you again would I add the args to the wdio file as listed? services: ['selenium-standalone'],
    seleniumArgs: {
        seleniumArgs: ["-port", "7777"],
      },

Comment: Hey @Gbru!
I didn't get you, could you please rephrase?

Comment: Hey @Yevhen, currently I'm constructing a framework using webdriverio (https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile.html) would you know how to add the seleniumArgs inside the wdio file instead of needing the pass the port number via command line? thanks

Comment: Oh, I get it. I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
nodejs webdriver-manager start --seleniumPort 5555
```